# How i can store bearer tokens on server-side and after validate how to delete on logout in Web API 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin, restful-authentication

I am creating web api project, by default it have account controller in which i found Register,Logout and other api's .
Using Web API 2, OAuth and OWIN

By /token i generated bearer token and his expiry time which is storing in OWIN Cookie authentication.

My Question is : -

- how i can delete this token when user logout because after using logout service i can still call list data which is decorated with [Authorize]
- can i store it in database and validate it, delete it when user logout

Logout code is below

```
    // POST api/Account/Logout
    [Route("Logout")]
    public IHttpActionResult Logout()
    {
        // Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
return ok();
```

}

and my /token code is below

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete the token in server, however you can forget the token in client side.
Or you can create refresh token service

Just create the class

```
public class SimpleRefreshTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider {
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket> _refreshTokens = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket>();
        public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context) {
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            _refreshTokens.TryAdd(guid, context.Ticket);
           context.SetToken(guid);
        }

        public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context) {
            AuthenticationTicket ticket;
            if (_refreshTokens.TryRemove(context.Token, out ticket)) {
                context.SetTicket(ticket);
            }
        } 
    }
```

Register it in

```
static Startup() {
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Login"),
                Provider = new OAuthProvider(),
                RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider(),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            };
        }
```

Override OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

```
public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context) {       
        if (context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret)) {
            if (clientSecret == "secret") {
                context.OwinContext.Set<string>("as:client_id", clientId);
                context.Validated();
            }
        }
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
```

}

and your service request should be look like this

```
Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50MTpzZWNyZXQ=
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

username=care%40agentExperience.com&password=test&client_id=client1&clientSecret=secret&grant_type=refresh_token
```

Comment: ,If server will restart unfortunately. Shall token will automatic delete ? If yes then I need to ignore this situation but don't know how

Comment: Then how I will logout user from app, suppose I deleted token from client side what happen if someone got token and will access information .how to handle this

Comment: And what if there is no internet connection available, User shutdown it's computer unexpectedly, computer crashes, In that case you never ever able to delete token from database using logout.

Comment: Minimize your token expiry time

Comment: what is clientId, clientSecret?   client_id=client1&clientSecret=secret